# How to keep visibility while restricting the accessibility of conditionalPanel()?

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements, shinyapps

I have a `conditionalPanel()`. I am seeking a solution that will keep the `conditionalPanel()` visible but not accessible if the condition is not met.

The condition is when `input$n_sygdom >= 1`, then show/activate `input$ecs` and `input$contra.pos`.

I currently have

[image]

With the script

```
library(shiny)
library(survminer)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Survival Curve of individualized pN-staging\n"),

  br(),

  fluidRow(

    column(3,
           wellPanel(style = "height:150px", sliderInput("n_fjernet", "Lymph Nodal Yield", min = 2, max = 120, value = 40))
    ),

    column(3,
           wellPanel(style = "height:150px", sliderInput("n_sygdom", "Number of positive lymph nodes", min = 0, max = 40, value = 0))
    ),

    column(3,
           wellPanel(style = "height:150px", conditionalPanel(
                                                    condition = "input.n_sygdom >= 1", 
                                                    radioButtons("ecs", "Extracapsular extension", c("No","Yes"))))
    ),

    column(3,
           wellPanel(style = "height:150px", conditionalPanel(
                                             condition = "input.n_sygdom >= 1", 
                                             radioButtons("contra.pos", "Neck involvement", c("Contra.","Ipsi."))))
    )

  ),
  br(),

  #Row of Outputs (make sure the columns sum to 12)
  fluidRow(

    column(12, align="center"
    ),

    column(12, align="center")
    )

)



server <- function(input, output, session) {


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I do not like how `input$ecs` and `input$contra.pos` just are two grey boxes when `input$n_sygdom==0`.

I am seeking a solution that will make `input$ecs` and `input$contra.pos` visible if `input$n_sygdom==0` but not accessible.

Like this for `input$n_sygdom==0`:

[image]

And like this for `input$n_sygdom >= 1`

[image]

Comment: Maybe with `shinyjs::disable`?

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent. Thank you for commenting. I am not familiar with `shinyjs::disable`. I am completely new to `Shiny`. Perhaps, could I persuade you into writing me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do with `shinyjs::disable`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),

  titlePanel("Survival Curve of individualized pN-staging\n"),

  br(),

  fluidRow(

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        sliderInput("n_fjernet", "Lymph Nodal Yield", 
                    min = 2, max = 120, value = 40)
      )
    ),

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        sliderInput("n_sygdom", "Number of positive lymph nodes", 
                    min = 0, max = 40, value = 0)
      )
    ),

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        radioButtons("ecs", "Extracapsular extension", c("No","Yes"))
      )
    ),

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        radioButtons("contra_pos", "Neck involvement", c("Contra.","Ipsi."))
      )
    )

  )

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input[["n_sygdom"]], {
    if(input[["n_sygdom"]] < 1){
      disable("ecs")
      disable("contra_pos")
    }else{
      enable("ecs")
      enable("contra_pos")
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent. Thank you, it is much appreciated. That did exactly what I requested; however, it has resulted in a new problem, which I've posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118875/why-does-renderplot-not-print-the-ggsurvplot-in-shiny

Comment: @cmirian I've changed `input$contra.pos` to `input$contra_pos`, because the dots in an id are to be avoided. In your other post, you mix `contra.pos` and `contra_pos`.

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent. Yes, I completely overlooked that. Thank you very much! I wish you a great day.